# How to select multiple (dice) buttons in VUE2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, vuejs2

I have dice buttons:

```
<template >
<div>
        <div class="fiveDice"  >
                <button v-model="diceroll" class="dice textHover" v-for="(dicecode, index) in diceroll" v-html="css[dicecode]"   @click="holdDice($event)"></button>
                           
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button id="btn" class="btn wHover" @click="roleNumber();">Gooien</button>
            <button id="btnFill" class="btn wHover">Vul score in</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        
</div>
```

When you click the button with @click="RoleNumber()"
It will output buttons with dice uni code, it will show 5 dice.

I want it to be possible to select multiple dice so you can hold them, and the rest that is not selected will be thrown. (Its Yahtzee the game)

So I use the event option to target them with:

```
 holdDice: function(event) {
            console.log(event);
                    

}
```

But the console.log(event) outputs ALOT , when I read the output in the console and see inner.html it does target the specific dice.

My guess is a loop in the function but how to target them properly. Event.value does not work. event.target.value also does not work. It will show undefined.

How do I make it so that I can select multiple ? I guess loop trough it. I am totally new to VUE, I am learning VUE2 now. Anybody can guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I would make a dice array in my data and make each button switch their own

```
boolean:
diceHeld : {
 die1 : false,
  die2 : false,
die3 : false,
die4 : false,
die5 : false
}
```

Then your "hold" buttons you just address the die directly with something

```
@click="diceHeld.die1 = !diceHeld.die1"
```

You can use the same object to determine if the button should look "selected" or not AND you can just look in this object when rolling to see which dice you need to reroll.

---

Edit 1:
Note this isnt the complete solution you're looking for but it works and should point you in a working direction.

You could make the HTML like this

```
<div>
    <div class="die" v-for="diceNumber in numberOfDice" :style="{'background-color' : selectedDiceObject['dice' + diceNumber] ? 'red' : 'green'}" @click="toggleDice(diceNumber)">{{diceNumber}}</div>
</div>
```

and the JS part like this:

```
{
  el: '#vueApp',
  data: function () {
    return {
      numberOfDice: 5,
      selectedDiceObject: { dice1: false, dice2: false, dice3: false, dice4: false, dice5: false  }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDice: function (diceNum) {
      this.selectedDiceObject['dice' + diceNum] = !this.selectedDiceObject['dice' + diceNum];
    }
  },
};
```

Notice that the dice-buttons background-color is set to reflect its state

---

Edit2:
Now that the blood has started flowing back to my brain from my stomac I think I would solve it in a slightly different manner:

Html :

```
<div v-if="selectedDiceObject">
    <div class="die" v-for="dob in selectedDiceObject" :style="{'background-color' : dob.selected ? 'red' : 'green'}" @click="dob.selected = !dob.selected">{{dob.result}}</div>
</div>
<button @click="roll">roll</button>
```

JS:

```
{
  el: '#vueApp',
  data: function () {
    return {
      numberOfDice: 5,
      selectedDiceObject: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    roll: function () {
      for(dicekey in this.selectedDiceObject) {
        if (!this.selectedDiceObject[dicekey].selected)
        this.selectedDiceObject[dicekey].result = Math.round( (Math.random() * 5) + 1);
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    let workObj = {};
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.numberOfDice; i++) {
      workObj['dice' + i] = { selected : false, result : 0 };
    }
    this.selectedDiceObject = workObj;
  }

};
```

Notice here, I use the dice object to hold both the current roll and wether it is selected. This way I can use the same for to control all aspecte of every single dice without much more code.

One of the new things is that I initialize the dice in the mounted event. I could as well fetch data from a server here, but now its completely dynamic.  Just set another numberOfDice and viola..  You now work with that number of dice.

Comment: Thanks,I am trying now something that you say. My data is:

              diceroll: [],
              css: {1: "&#x2680;", 2: "&#x2681;", 3: "&#x2682;", 4: "&#x2683;", 5:"&#x2684;", 
              6: "&#x2685;" },
              dicehold: {1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false , 5:false},

My dicerolls  are a random nr. So now just a loop to match the same nr in the function ? Because what you are saying is I have to generate with a v-for the @Click="Diceheld.Die+random output to get the correct nr , is that possible ?Or am I overthinking?

edit: My comment is to hard to read perhaps?

Comment: I've updated my ansver to help you further.
One extra improvement is that you could generate the "selectedDiceObject" object at runtime in the "mounted" event.
Then you could generate your dice-buttons based on that object.